# Include date in filename for cshell

Tags: shell, csh

I'm struggling with the naming of the log file after i'm executing a cpp program and afterwards i'm redirecting the cout and cerr to different log files. I want to get the current date and name the logs according to following format:

```
date_cout.log
date_cerr.log
```

Cshell script used:

```
(./test > $(date+"%y%m%d)_cout.log > & $(date+"%y%m%d)_cerr.log
```

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: You can't write `date+%y%m%d` without the space between `date` and `+%y%m%d` any more than you can write `ls-l` without the space between `ls` and `-l`. Also, you've got a bunch of mismatched quotes (if you're going to put `%y%m%d` in quotes, you need to put ending quotes after the end of it). There may be other problems as well, but fix the basic typos first, and then tell us what behavior you get when you actually run this code.

Comment: (Also, why are you using csh in 2021? https://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/csh.whynot and https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt are relevant classic essays on why csh has been considered something that should not be used for new code for many decades now -- probably longer than most of the folks on this site have been alive).

Comment: Hi, thank you both for replay. When i wrote the code on my machine (i use different machine for linux) i wrote without ending " but on the linux csh i wrote with them also i tried this morning with (./test > $(date + "%y%m%d")_cout.log ) > &  $(date + "%y%m%d")_cerr.log) and i receive the error illegal variable name

Comment: In sh, not csh, the new version would be sort of closer to correct, but you'd want to change `> &` to `2>` (and note the removal of the space, it's important). I'm not enough of an expert to tell you how to fix it in csh, however. (You also have a space between the `+` and the `"` that isn't legal in the `date` commands -- you can't add or remove quotes willy-nilly in shell languages; the details matter).

Comment: A _properly correct_ approach for sh would look like `./test >"$(date +"%y%m%d")_cout.log" 2>"$(date +"%y%m%d")_cerr.log"` -- though it would be better to run `date` just once and store the result in a variable, so running this code right at midnight couldn't have two different files for stdout and stderr (and so you wouldn't pay the performance cost of running an external command in a subshell twice).

Answer (score 0):

The csh way to do it is

```
(./test.csh > `date +'%y%m%d'`_cout.log) >& `date +'%y%m%d'`_cerr.log
```

But you you have other options, like bash, better to avoid csh.